# Manjaro Linux on Thinkpad E570. Everything runs great and is plug and play, except my volume up and down. These are the function keys, (f1,f2, etc)

Tags: linux, keyboard, thinkpad, manjaro

I am a complete newbie and I recognize my lack of knowledge, I tried using some terminal commands but nothing seems to work. My function keys dont work,the volume up (f3), volume down(f2), bluetooth(f10), mute(f1), etc. Hopefully I learn more through this troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you tried with FN?

Comment: Yes I have tried the FN key and FNLock